# How to set byteCode level when creating a android library module in android studio 4.1.1?

Tags: android, module, android-gradle-plugin, bytecode

This image shows the pop up dialog when we create a new module from the list of module types. Here i have selected Android Library.
[This image shows the pop up dialog when we create a new module from the list of module types.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azITj.png)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that this setting represents the `compileOptions` and `kotlinOptions`.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

For example, if you set ByteCode Level to 6, the `compileOptions` and `kotlinOptions` in the `build.gradle` of the module you created will look like this.

```
android {
    .
    .
    .
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.6'
    }
}
```

Also, if ByteCode Level is set to 8, the following will be shown.

```
android {
    .
    .
    .
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}
```